# Steam not running

Tags: 12.04, steam

I have just installed steam but when I double click on the icon, it does nothing.

If i try to start steam from the terminal I get this:

This is what it says:

```
jonathon@BACAGE:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/home/jonathon/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704:  5275 Illegal instruction
     $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Installing bootstrap /home/jonathon/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/jonathon/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
/home/jonathon/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704:  5361 Illegal instruction
     $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Steam for Linux client requires a processor that supports SSE2. If your processor does not support SSE2, the Steam client will not run. If you run the Steam client from the command-line, you will  see an illegal instruction exception caused by the lack of SSE2 support.
In order to run Steam for Linux you will need to upgrade to a processor that supports SSE2.

-- [Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7420-QROP-9359)

This page (Wikipedia) displays common [compatible processors for SSE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#CPUs_supporting_SSE2)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Steam launcher like so:

```
$ STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam
```

As seen [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/1075)

Comment: This has given me the same error expect the number before the first `Illegal instruction` is 2724 and the second has changed to 2809

Comment: Could you tell me if your processor supports any form of SSE?
`cat /proc/cpuinfo`, 
It will be under "flags:" if it is there.

Comment: SSE is listed under flags

Comment: Is SSE2? I believe SSE may be essential

Comment: Only SSE is listed. But after you mentioning it, and a quick Google search, it look like you may be correct.

Comment: Indeed, it's a pain having to get new hardware to support software given it's price etc, sorry to deliver the bad news; would you consider this question answered?